# .exe doesn't run after building from .py

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I am beginner at python. I have just created a script which includes a Tkinter GUI application. Whenever i run it using cmd it works fine but whenever i tried to create an exe of it using pyinstaller or cx_Freeze it won't run. It just pops up console and terminates within a second.

Comment: What did you do to build the exe?

Comment: Your previous question was closed because it didn't include any details like code to replicata the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550948/cant-run-script-when-i-convert-py-to-exe So... you just copied the same question again?

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that using cmd, it **starts** the program and does not terminate until you close the shell, and the tkinter window stays open, but when you use an `exe` file, it terminates after all the code is run once, so you should probably have a `while` loop running preferably forever until the window is closed by you.

Comment: He's using Tkinter, so probably he didn't call `tkinter.Tk.mainloop()`